# Join same table and fetch sub folders in mysql query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, querying

I have a table for saving "folders" in a document management system.Table structure given below

```
folder_id
name
parent_id
```

Here `parent_id` is reference key for same table to point its parent folder.So I need to retrieve all folders ids from a folder id.ie,Sub folders list of a folder.

Is it possible to get in a single query as self join?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Select d.folder_id from folders as d, folders as e where d.parent_id = e.folder_id
```

Comment: I want to retrieve only all sub folder ids of a folder.ie,support my folder id 15,then retrieve its sub folder and again sub folder of its sub-folder if exist.